# Any good source of fxml thempletes?

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

I am working with **javafx 2.2** in some project for my studies using **fxml** as well for my GUI , since i am really bad in design ,i am looking for interesting design , i looked all over the internet but there's no good news.
Can anyone provide me a site or any good samples to use ?

Comment: What samples, what design? Please form your question properly. In what do you need help? What do you expect from the "samples"?

Comment: as for web when we have a ready themplate to use it to make a website like those we can get from [templatemonster](http://www.templatemonster.com) or [templated](http://templated.co) etc..
i just want the same thing for a desktop application as i mentioned in my question